# console.log/warn/error - native, vanilla JavaScript more performant alternative?

Tags: javascript, performance, console, firebug, console.log

I have done a bit of research and most of what I find is a good few years old. I’m new to JS and I’m building up my knowledge gradually.

Console.log() is an incredibly helpful tool, however I’m incredibly wary of its generally poor performance (https://jsperf.com/console-log1337/16 or https://jsperf.com/console-log1337/33 as a basic example), as well as bad reputation.

In the event I need to leave console.log() style error messages in a production application/website, is there a more performant alternative that is native to vanilla JS (no frameworks/libraries)?

My initial thought was to instead push all log items into an array which could later be collected (if required) however it seems that doesn’t work in conjunction with Promise.all() very well - rather than getting say, 10 items in an array, I instead get back either a single array with the last value, or 10 separate arrays.

Is there a native or most recommended alternative (appreciate this is open to “opinion” - I’m not sure how else to word it!)?

Ps - apologies for lack of formatting... mobile!

Comment: console.log calls won't slow down your site unless they are being called incredibly frequently.  A smart approach to programming is to never worry about performance until you need to.  If you're constantly worrying about micro-performance of every command you will get too bogged down in the details and kill your productivity.

Comment: To address your specific issue - you could look into a metrics gathering service like google analytics and send relevant data to that, should be more useful than console logs that would require you to manually go check on every issue a user reports.

Comment: promise all, sounds like you are using it wrong or misunderstanding asynchronous calls.

Comment: @irkeninvader - how frequently is too frequently though? Are we talking 100s per second or more? I don’t attach them to scroll events (like some). I’m not majorly fussed about the few I have (maybe 30 or so when debugging, and not all of them get run) which helps me with step-through testing of functions and refactoring. Re: micro-optimisations, I couldn’t agree more. I’m not focusing on these as “issues”, but as more of a learning point. I know there’s a lot of framework stuff out there, but I’d ideally like to scrub up on native JS first :)

Comment: @epascarello - that may be the case, I’m still learning the “basics” to be honest. I’m currently leaning more toward .then()’ing some of the Promise.all() I have, as I think that it would be a more appropriate workflow -  but that’s off-topic! I don’t think storing the messages in an array are of as much use to be honest?

Comment: I wasn't sure about exact numbers so I wrote a test https://jsfiddle.net/y14cm8h2/, it looks like after 50,000 logs (done all at once) and someone might notice a hiccup...about 1/5th of a second for my machine.  If you open the inspector logs are about 10x slower so that number becomes 5,000 or so to get a noticible lag.  I'd say feel free to log to your hearts content :)

Comment: Nice! Thank you @irkeninvader!!!! I wonder how that relates on mobile - I’ll give it a whirl now! :) EDIT: Leaving it at the default values for that fiddle I see 16.5ms per with log (iPhone XS Max, Chrome) vs 0 without. However, I can’t increase from 1000 iterations without the page failing on me completely! Nice test though - information I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... poor performance

One of the testcases compares calling an empty function to calling `console.log`. An empty function will probably be inlined by the JIT compiler, so you are actually comparing *no code at all* to `console.log`. For sure *no code at all* is way faster.

I never experienced any (noticible) lag due to logging, except you are logging inside a render loop or anything executed very, very often.

> ... bad reputation

Seriously? In my eyes JS has great ways to debug compared to other languages (probably because JS got the nicest bugs :)) as you can view nested structures "live", you can halt execution at breakpoints, you can prepare code for debugging with the `debugger;` statement, you can dump the whole memory, visualize GC behaviour, hot functions and much more. Yes, all those features lower performance, however the console performs quite well.

> is there a more performant alternative that is native to vanilla JS (no frameworks/libraries)?

The logging is directly written into the engine executing JavaScript, that means it can access a lot of things that you cannot access through JS, also native code will always be faster than compiled JavaScript (or equally fast, but no one can guarantee that).

> In the event I need to leave console.log() style error messages in a production application/website ...

And who should read this logs? Do you want to ask your client to look into the console in the case of an error?

Logging in Production should not log everything you use through debugging, but just enough that you can track down errors, so some breadcrumbs to find out  where the error occured (e.g. "menu open"), and the errors themselves.

If you don't want to write production logging by yourself, have a look at [sentry for JS](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: `The logging is directly written into the engine executing JavaScript, that means it can access a lot of things that you cannot access through JS, also native code will always be faster than compiled JavaScript.` +1 for this line

Comment: Thanks Jonas - this is actually incredibly helpful/insightful! :) I tried to research this (based on a conversation I had) however every example case I found always compared console.log to an empty function, which I did think was strange because an empty function isn’t doing anything! Re: the “bad rep” - I was referring specifically to console.log. It seems to have a really bad name, almost hated based on everything I’ve seen/heard lately (almost as bad as eval!). Re: access to the logs - it’s not writing anything “sensitive” per se, so is open to clients/end users for troubleshooting/diag.

Comment: By the sounds of it, sticking with a few console.logs isn’t going to be a bad thing! I’m not attaching them to scroll events or anything like that - I have a version purely for debugging/step-by-step indicators, and a version with 90% of console.log stripped out.

Comment: @willstocks_tech well clients shouldn't have access to sensitive data at all ... I mean it is just a bad user experience, looking at the console is the developer's not the user's job. "I've heard lately" ... who said that?

Comment: @jonas-wilms no, they don’t and I wouldn’t allow it. It was more for surface level debugging on their end. To make it a bit easier to “troubleshoot” themselves (or to provide me with the info a bit easier - lol!) as the end client are fairly savvy in themselves and might be able to work out they’re passing something in the wrong format etc.. “I’ve heard lately” - mainly conversations around the workplace and with third party devs (although they’re a bit old school... so might be a personality type thing!!!). There were a few posts I came across on SO as well!

Comment: Accepted as answer - thanks for the insight Jonas it has really helped me understand a bit more!! Ordering more books now and scrubbing up further :)